# How do I play a video in the YouTube app at zero volume while simultaneously playing music in an MP3 player app?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, huawei, music, youtube

Sometimes, I love to play music at a high volume while watching text YouTube videos and muting YouTube, like what I do on PC.

I have a Huawei phone running Android 5.0 (Lollipop).

Answer (score 0):

Find an app that works similar to multiscreen on Samsung devices. I use a Samsung and it comes preloaded with multiscreen. You may find an alternative on the play store.

Comment: nah i didn't find one on Huawei